# Templates in KnockoutJS, empty string isn't rendering

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I've got a problem using KnockoutJS to render a two dimensional array as a table. I've created a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/postmoderncore/RtphC/), but this is the relevant template code:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="resultRowTemplate">
    <tr data-bind="template: { name: 'resultColumnTemplate', foreach: $data }"></tr>
</script>

<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="resultColumnTemplate">
    <td>-${$data}-</td>
</script>

<table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'resultRowTemplate', foreach: Results }"></tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is that resultColumnTemplate isn't rendered when the data is an empty string. I'm guessing something internal treats the empty string as null/false and decides it shouldn't be rendered.

You can see this in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/postmoderncore/RtphC/). I'd expect it to render as

```
-1- -2-
--  -4-
```

Instead of what I'm seeing:

```
-1- -2-
-4-
```

I've got a workaround by changing my data so empty string is replaced by a single space, but was hoping someone may have a better suggestion or understanding of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout puts each item into its own array before sending it through the jQuery Templates plugin, so that it will not try to unwrap items that are arrays themselves.

It appears that jQuery Templates does not render array items that are empty/null/undefined.

I think that your options are:

- do what you did (replace item with " ")
- remove the inner-most template and do a `{{each}}` over your array
- map your array to use objects `[{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: ""}, {value: 4}]`

Comment: Thanks for that. Have used the `{{each}}` suggestion, seems the lightest and least hackish solution. I'll hold off marking you as the answer for a little while in case someone else has something neater still.